# Knowing How to Detect a Disconnection when Reading Socket Data (InputStream)

Tags: java, sockets, stream, network-programming

I have a thread that is constantly reading data from an InputStream.  The InputStream data is coming from a Bluetooth socket. Previously, I wasn't using the if(mmInStream.available() > 0) around the InputStream read statement and when the bluetooth socket went away (someone turned off the device), the mmInStream.read would throw a IOException and then I could process my disconnection logic. What is the best way to determine when a disconnect has occurred?

First byte of 0xEE tells me its the leader of the data packet and the second tells me the length to read.

```
public void run() {
            byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[1024];
            byte[] buffer = null;
            int byteRead=0;
        long timeout=0;
        long wait=100;

            while (true) {
                try {
                timeout = System.currentTimeMillis() + wait;
                    if(mmInStream.available() > 0) {
                        while((mmInStream.available() > 0) && (tempBuffer[0] != (byte) 0xEE) && (System.currentTimeMillis() < timeout)){
                        byteRead = mmInStream.read(tempBuffer, 0, 1);
                    }
                    if(tempBuffer[0] == (byte) 0xEE){
                        timeout = System.currentTimeMillis() + wait; 
                        while(byteRead<2 && (System.currentTimeMillis() < timeout)){
                            byteRead += mmInStream.read(tempBuffer, 1, 1); 
                        }
                    }
                    timeout = System.currentTimeMillis() + wait; 
                    while((byteRead<tempBuffer[1]) && (System.currentTimeMillis() < timeout)){
                        byteRead += mmInStream.read(tempBuffer, byteRead, tempBuffer[1]-byteRead); 
                    }
                    }

                    if(byteRead > 0){
                        //do something with the bytes read in               
                    } 
                }

                catch (IOException e) {
                    bluetoothConnectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all this malarkey with available(). Just set a read timeout with setSoTimeout, read, detect read returning -1, use the count returned by read if > 0 rather than assuming the buffer got filled, catch SocketTimeoutException to detect read timeouts, and catch IOException to detect other breakages.

Answer (score 0):

After a look at the documentation, I think it's like this:

```
public void run() {
    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int byteRead = 0;

    while (true) {
        try {
            bytesRead = mmInStream.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length);
            if (bytesRead < 0)
                // End of stream.
                break;

            // Do something with the bytes read in. There are bytesRead bytes in tempBuffer.
        } catch (IOException e) {
            bluetoothConnectionLost();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that is how I previously had the code, but we experienced data loss with this approach.  Inside the  if(mmInStream.available() > 0) check we inspect the first byte to make sure its the leader of the packet (else ignore) and then the second byte tells me the length to read, so I keep reading until that length.  I'll update my code to reflect this, was just trying to keep it simple

Comment: You could scan `tempBuffer` for the leader byte. If you find it, the following bytes will be the length and the data. Of course, you might still need to read some more bytes if they are not all there.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's like this:

```
 void fun(){
   isOpen = true;
   try{
      InputStream stream = socket.getInputStream();
      while(isOpen){
         byte[] buf = new byte[8];
         int pos = stream.read(buf);
         if (pos < 0) {
            throw new IOException();
         }
         //dosomething...
      }
  }catch(IOException e) {
    isOpen  = false;
  }finally{
    //do dispose here
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer